# Delete APN (Reset to Default)

Tags: android, apn

How can I program the "Reset to default" function from the APN menu in Android?
I used the code from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zhengpei/archive/2009/10/13/managing-apn-data-in-google-android.aspx to create and set a custom APN.  However, I would like to add functionality to my script to remove the custom entry from the APN list.
Is there a way to call the "Reset to default" function?
If not, how can I remove an APN?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If not, how can I remove an APN?

If you know which entry to delete, use [`ContentResolver.delete()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#insert%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

Here the URI will be : `Uri APN_TABLE_URI =  Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers");` and `Where` will be a filter to apply to rows before deleting, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself).

> Is there a way to call the "Reset to default" function?

To restore to default you need backup the default APN ID in the first place. If you back it up, you can call `SetDefaultAPN()` to restore it.

Try this out though, I saw it in [TelephonyProvider.java](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/src/com/android/providers/telephony/TelephonyProvider.java&exact_package=android&q=restoredefaultapn&type=cs&l=638). It seems risky so I suggest you [back up your APN's](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=apn%20backup%20android&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC0QFjAC&url=https://market.android.com/details?id=com.riteshsahu.APNBackupRestore&hl=en&ei=a0O7ToayJe6hmQWIxun1Bw&usg=AFQjCNG-AIuu-dBunJRqe3xmBwK2wSFmiw)

```
private void restoreDefaultAPN() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        db.delete(CARRIERS_TABLE, null, null);
        setPreferredApnId((long)-1);
        ((DatabaseHelper) mOpenHelper).initDatabase(db);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I implemented ContentResolver.delete().  Since I only had two APNs, it reactivated the default for me.  However, I probably should use the SetDefaultAPN() in case there are more than two. I appreciate your help.